# ActiveMQ Classic embedded broker not reporting tempStorageUsage and erroring on disk full

Tags: activemq-classic

I have an embedded ActiveMQ Classic broker. It is configured for KahaDB persistence. The broker is started with `SystemUsage` object including `tempStore` limits.  I have a queue policy that uses `StorePendingQueueMessageStoragePolicy` and `producerFlowControl=true`. The queue memory size is 100MB.

When I send messages I can see the messages stored in `tempStore` and the queue size is over 100MB.  However, the `brokerView` reports 0% usage. When the `tempStore` fills up the disk, the broker errors with an exception

```
java.io.IOException: Async Writer Thread Shutdown
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.DataFileAppender.enqueue(DataFileAppender.java:164) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.DataFileAppender.storeItem(DataFileAppender.java:129) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal.write(Journal.java:961) ~[broker.jar:?]
```

The `tempStore` is automatically configured when the KahaDB persistence adapter is started.

How can I report the `tempStore` usage?

Comment: Are you sure that: there is no disk error/corruption? permissions are okay? and `tempDataStore` directory is correctly specified?

Comment: Yes, it is all set up correctly and I can see the store being used.